# How to create a dynamic PDF on the server side using classic asp/com/activex?

Tags: pdf, dynamic, com, asp-classic, activex

The way I need this to work is as follows:

1. There will already be a PDF form on
   the server that serves as a template
   for the final PDF.
2. A user fills out a web form and
   submits it to the server.
3. The information the user submitted
   via the web form then populates
   predetermined fields on the PDF then
   saves a copy of the PDF with the
   users' data.

Is there a free tool/software out there for this?

If this is possible what tool/app/com/active x object works the best?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably no way to find free ASP/ActiveX object to fill PDF forms which is free of charge and not under GPL-like license. AFAIK the cheapest tool (about 25 USD) that is capable of filling forms from a command line is PDF Toolkit (http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk/ ). This tool is under open source GPL license but commercial license is available at 25 USD per unit.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have a budget for this sort of thing but Adobe Acrobat X professional allows you to create a template pdf that contains form fields and can submit to an HTTP listener like an ASP page.

This would eliminate the need for really any custom code at all and only requires the user have a viable PDF reader installed.  You can serve the PDF template to the user via HTTP, it will open the PDF reader program for the user, the user can fill out the fields, and then press a button on the document to submit the form filled document to the server.

Of course if this isn't your fancy, I think there is a version of iText for .NET that is really awesome.

Comment: And don't forget that latest versions of iText/iTextSharp will also require "a budget" for commercial license unless we are talking about an open source project here.

Comment: Good point... I am hard pressed to find an open source or freeware offering on the .NET platform that gives you this.  There are several good ones for Java that I have used, Apache pdfbox and iText Java to name a few.  I seem to remember a couple years ago on a .NET project where I was manipulating PDF files programatically but for the life of me I can't remember the tool or if it was a paid license.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend [Amyuni PDF Creator ActiveX](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreatoractivex) for this. It is not free, but it does definitely suits your needs.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am part of the development team of this product.